# Existence of a generic ultrafilter over constructible universe

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am referring to the Jech's "Set Theory" book.
He wants to show that, if $(P,<)$ is the notion of forcing defined as:

$p \in P$ iff $p$ is a finite sequence of ordinals less than $\omega_{1}^{L}$ and $p<q$ iff $p \supset q$

then $L[G]\models \omega_{1}^{L}$ is countable.

So the author wants to show that is consistent that $P$ has a generic filter in $L$.
Let $B$ be the completion of $P$ in $L$. I'm working in the boolean value model $L^{B}$. Let's call $D=\mathcal{P}^{L}(B)$ and let G be the canonical ultrafilter.

I already know that $\lVert$ G is a $\check{D}$-generic ultrafilter $\rVert$=1

I can't understand how to show $\lVert$ $\check{D}$ is the set of all constructible subset of $\check{B}$ $\rVert$ =1

But let's say I demonstrate that last line above. Why isn't this enought for what I want to proof? Why Jech also say that we use that construibility is absolute in boolean universe and so is the definition of $P$?
Where am I wrong when i just say:

1=$\lVert$ G is a $\check{D}$-generic ultrafilter $\rVert$ $\lVert$ $\check{D}=\mathcal{P}^{L}(\check{B})$ $\rVert$ $\le$ $\lVert$ G is a $\mathcal{P}^{L}(\check{B})$-generic ultrafilter $\rVert$

Comment: Whatever $B$ is (you never said), $D$ is certainly not $\mathcal P(B)$ in the generic extension. Is that a typo in the last line? Did you mean $\mathcal P^L(B)$ instead of $\mathcal P(B)$?

Comment: What does $L$ mean here? The class $L(=L^L)$, as computed in the ground model $L$, or the class $L^{L[G]}$, as computed in the new universe? Since you want to show that $L[G]\models$"$\omega_1^L$ is countable", it should mean $L^{L[G]}$. Since the argument instead shows that $\omega_1^{L^{L}}$ is countable, you need to show that $\omega_1^{L^L}=\omega_1^{L^{L[G]}}$, which follows from the stronger absoluteness claim that Jech mentions.

Comment: $B$ is r.o.$(P)^{L}$. Given a partial order $P$, r.o(P) is a complete boolean algebra in which $P$ can be embedded (not necessarily one-to-one) through $e$ such that $e(P)$ is dense in $B$ and such that order relation and compatibility are preserved.

Comment: (1) You should **definitely** use different type settings if you have $P$ for both power set and forcing notion. (2) You should **definitely** add the fact that $B$ is the completion of $(P)^L$ (where do we complete it? in $V$ or in $L$ or elsewhere?) to the post. People shouldn't sift through comments for this sort of information.

Comment: I've done some editing, hope now it's better. Now, $L$ is the ground model, and I am completing $P$ in $L$ since i want to work in boolean model $L^{B}$. @AndresCaicedo I'm not really interested in which ordinal is shown to be countable, but how in the boolean model $L^{B}$ the sentence "there exists a filter on $P$, generic on the constructible universe" has value 1.

Comment: The question is either trivial, using the argument in your last line, or it amounts to showing that $\mathcal P^L(B)$ is the same, whether computed in $L$ or in the extension (which is the same sort of reasoning as showing that $\omega_1^L$ is the same whether computed in $L% or in the extension).

Comment: I still can't understand where do I must use the absoluteness of the definition of $P$.

Comment: Can you give a more accurate reference to Jech, perhaps?

Comment: I am referring to 1978 ed. Jech's "Set Theory", p. 175, the paragraph entitled "I: Consistency of a generic ultrafilter".

Comment: Oy vey. Why are you reading the 1978 edition?

Comment: I have 3rd millennium edition as well, and I usually refer to that, I just couldn't find that passage in last edition.

Comment: The absoluteness of L is used in saying that, in the "boolean extension", D (or rather its canonical name) still contains all constructible subsets of B. I personally don't like mentioning "boolean valued universes" in an introduction to forcing. If you are trying to learn forcing, I would say, read Kunen's 1980 book first (ctm approach) and do a lot of problems there before reading jech's books.